# How to deal with a features that overweight others in a regression?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, nonlinear-regression, feature-engineering

I have been facing a problem that has been taking quite a while to over. In my problem I have basically 3 input features in my model and one single output. I have been using GP to fit my model to data, and afterwards, I perform a minimization to my model as I want to find out the set of inputs that return the optimal . The picture bellow shows the Spearman correlation heatmap:

[image]

What is more interesting to me in my data is the interaction of two features and how the influence the output, in this case, $\alpha _1$ and $\alpha_2$. The problem is that these features are overweighted by $\theta$, which completely breaks my model.

One option could be separate the theta in really small intervals where the variance is low and then try to explore better the effect of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ over $y$. However, unfortunately this wouldn't be possible due to my sample data.

So my question is: os there any statistical trick to eliminate or at least diminish this influence without having to eliminate this features that overweights the model ($\theta$)?